# Merging Checkstyle XML Documents with identical structure using groovy

Tags: groovy, checkstyle

Good Morning

I have several Checkstyle XML reports with identical structure that I need to merge into a single document, the document looks as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<checkstyle version="6.15">
<file name="/media/sf_Google_Drive/Development/av_microservice/av_microservice/av_microservice_commons/src/main/java/za/co/av/ms_commons/communication/EMailMessage.java">
</file>
<file name="/media/sf_Google_Drive/Development/av_microservice/av_microservice/av_microservice_commons/src/main/java/za/co/av/ms_commons/communication/EMailSender.java">
</file>
<file name="/media/sf_Google_Drive/Development/av_microservice/av_microservice/av_microservice_commons/src/main/java/za/co/av/ms_commons/communication/SMSMessage.java">
</file>
<file name="/media/sf_Google_Drive/Development/av_microservice/av_microservice/av_microservice_commons/src/main/java/za/co/av/ms_commons/communication/package-info.java">
</file>
<file name="/media/sf_Google_Drive/Development/av_microservice/av_microservice/av_microservice_commons/src/main/java/za/co/av/ms_commons/ussd/InputValidation.java">
</file>
<file name="/media/sf_Google_Drive/Development/av_microservice/av_microservice/av_microservice_commons/src/main/java/za/co/av/ms_commons/ussd/InputValidationALL.java">
</file>
<file name="/media/sf_Google_Drive/Development/av_microservice/av_microservice/av_microservice_commons/src/main/java/za/co/av/ms_commons/ussd/InputValidationINTEGER.java">
</file>
<file name="/media/sf_Google_Drive/Development/av_microservice/av_microservice/av_microservice_commons/src/main/java/za/co/av/ms_commons/ussd/InputValidationTEXT.java">
</file>
<file name="/media/sf_Google_Drive/Development/av_microservice/av_microservice/av_microservice_commons/src/main/java/za/co/av/ms_commons/ussd/MenuNavigationEvent.java">
</file>
<file name="/media/sf_Google_Drive/Development/av_microservice/av_microservice/av_microservice_commons/src/main/java/za/co/av/ms_commons/ussd/SubscriberForUSSD.java">
</file>
<file name="/media/sf_Google_Drive/Development/av_microservice/av_microservice/av_microservice_commons/src/main/java/za/co/av/ms_commons/ussd/USSDMenuItem.java">
<error line="327" severity="error" message="Line is longer than 120 characters (found 157)." source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.sizes.LineLengthCheck"/>
<error line="327" column="133" severity="error" message="&apos;,&apos; is not followed by whitespace." source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.whitespace.WhitespaceAfterCheck"/>
</file>
<file name="/media/sf_Google_Drive/Development/av_microservice/av_microservice/av_microservice_commons/src/main/java/za/co/av/ms_commons/ussd/USSDMenuItemManager.java">
</file>
<file name="/media/sf_Google_Drive/Development/av_microservice/av_microservice/av_microservice_commons/src/main/java/za/co/av/ms_commons/ussd/USSDResponse.java">
</file>
<file name="/media/sf_Google_Drive/Development/av_microservice/av_microservice/av_microservice_commons/src/main/java/za/co/av/ms_commons/ussd/package-info.java">
</file>
<file name="/media/sf_Google_Drive/Development/av_microservice/av_microservice/av_microservice_commons/src/main/java/za/co/av/ms_commons/utils/DateUtils.java">
</file>
<file name="/media/sf_Google_Drive/Development/av_microservice/av_microservice/av_microservice_commons/src/main/java/za/co/av/ms_commons/utils/DbUtils.java">
</file>
<file name="/media/sf_Google_Drive/Development/av_microservice/av_microservice/av_microservice_commons/src/main/java/za/co/av/ms_commons/utils/Enumerators.java">
</file>
<file name="/media/sf_Google_Drive/Development/av_microservice/av_microservice/av_microservice_commons/src/main/java/za/co/av/ms_commons/utils/IDNumberValidator.java">
</file>
<file name="/media/sf_Google_Drive/Development/av_microservice/av_microservice/av_microservice_commons/src/main/java/za/co/av/ms_commons/utils/SimpleHTTP.java">
</file>
<file name="/media/sf_Google_Drive/Development/av_microservice/av_microservice/av_microservice_commons/src/main/java/za/co/av/ms_commons/utils/TextParser.java">
</file>
<file name="/media/sf_Google_Drive/Development/av_microservice/av_microservice/av_microservice_commons/src/main/java/za/co/av/ms_commons/utils/package-info.java">
</file>
</checkstyle>
```

now I have tried to merge using the following code

```
def list = []        
//create new XML file
File newXMLfile= new File("${rootProject.projectDir}/reports/checkStyleCombined.xml" ) 
new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
    mkp.xmlDeclaration([version:'1.0', encoding:'UTF-8', standalone:'no'])
    checkstyle {
        //get list of all checkstyle reports
        def dir = new File("${rootProject.projectDir}/reports/checkstyle")
        dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file -> 
            list << file
        }
        //itterate though the list
        list.each {
            //parse xml file
            def gPathResult = new XmlSlurper().parse(it)   
            //find all "file" nodes in xml file
            gPathResult.file.each{
                TEST(XmlUtil.serialize(it)) 
                out << it
            }
        }
    }
}.writeTo(newXMLfile.newWriter("UTF-8"))
```

The issue I have is twofold firstly it seems that I cant use the XmlUtil.serialize method to write my node because it puts a XML declaration on each line and the formatting looks like this.

```
<TEST>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;&lt;file name="XXXXXX"/&gt;
```

Secondly you will note in the XML file that there is an element called file. I cant use the name file in the closure because file is a reserved word so I use "TEST" but this is obviously wrong. So My question is simple does anyone know how to do this in a more simple fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that the approach I was using was not ideal so what I have done is used one of the XML documents as a root document and merged the other documents into it as follows

```
def list = []    
    //This is for the checkstyle report!!!!!!
    //create new XML file
    File newXMLfile= new File("${rootProject.projectDir}/reports/checkStyleCombined.xml" ) 

    //get list of all checkstyle reports
    def dir = new File("${rootProject.projectDir}/reports/checkstyle")
    dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file -> 
        list << file
    }
    //set the root xml document to the first document is the list
    def root = new XmlSlurper().parse(list.first())  
    //itterate through the list
    list.each {
        if(it != list.first()) 
        {
            //parse xml file
            def gPathResult = new XmlSlurper().parse(it)   
            //find all file nodes in xml file
            gPathResult.file.each{
                //append node to root node
                root.appendNode(it)
            }
        }
    }
    //write the node to file
    newXMLfile.withWriter { outWriter ->
        XmlUtil.serialize( new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind{ mkp.yield root }, outWriter )
    }
```

I hope this helps someone someday as it took me quite a while to figure it out.